# EpiServer: get content in the currently selected language?

Tags: episerver

We have a block that pulls in content and displays it on our page. Right now, no matter what language I select in our language switcher, this is not being honored by our block.

As I am new to EpiServer and C# I think I have identified the following line of code as being the one that pulls in the data?

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
```

Can I rewrite this to only get content in the language that is currently selected by the user?

I am unsure how to combine it with the CultureInfo class.

Comment: Can you share some more code e.g. the line where you are retrieving the content? The line you have shared is retrieving the _service_ that is used to retrieve the content.

Comment: In what context is that code executed? Normally you wouldn't have to do anything, so I'm curious where/how that code is executed. However, if it's missing a language context it'll default to the master language.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
IContentLoader contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
PageData page = contentLoader.Get<PageData>(new ContentReference(1234) /*Your contentreferenceid to fetch ere*/, ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture);
```

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` determines the UI language, so it should primarily be used inside the Episerver user interface, not for content delivery. You may, however, be interested in `ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture`.